JavaScript page revisit
I am adding international country dial code in front of a input box of phone no using below code.
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    var input = document.querySelector("#phone1");      
    window.intlTelInput(input, {
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
        initialCountry: "gb", 
        separateDialCode: true,
    });
});

This code is working perfectly when I am browsing normally. I have a submit button in this page. After submitting form this page is redirect to next page. I have a back button in next page. Below code is working when I page back button in next page.
$(document).on("click", ".locationBack", function () {
    var property_id = $('.property_id').val()
    getPropertyInformation(property_id)
    stepActiveClass(1)
});

When I press back button Dial Code code is not working.

This happens properly because the page gets cached by browser, and when you back in history it renders the cached version which can lead to JavaScript not being re-executed or initialized.
A solution is using pageshow instead of $(document).ready(), which will triggered everytime a page is loaded, even if gets loaded from the browser's cache
$(window).on("pageshow", function(event) {
    const input = document.querySelector("#phone1");
    window.intlTelInput(input, {
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
        initialCountry: "gb", 
        separateDialCode: true,
    });
});

